# Scanning QR Code does not work with Google Autneticator on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, qr-code, google-authenticator

I am creating this QR-Code URL:

> ```
> otpauth://totp/TEST:asfadsf?secret=CBPhavYImNauHrVP9KuoR5eE2fO-b_7s&issuer=TEST&algorithm=SHA-1&digits=6&period=30
> ```

If i am scanning this code with the google authenticator on ios, i am  getting the message:

> "The Code is not a valid authentication token"

Is there anything wrong in my QR code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems and fixed them like the following:

**1. Issuer:**

I don't send the issuer and user separated with a ":" I only add the user name. The issuer information is already provided with &issuer="..."

**2. Secret:**

The secret needs to be a base32 (RFC 3548/4648) string. This basically means generated out of the following chars: "*ABCDEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz234567*"

Here's a function to generate a random secret as needed:

```
generateRandomSecretTFA(length = 32) {
 let randomBytes = itf.generateRandomBytes(length); // function from node.js crypto module generating random bytes
 let rfc3548chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz234567';
 let secret = '';
 for (let i = 0, l = randomBytes.length; i < l; i++) {
  secret += rfc3548chars[Math.floor(randomBytes[i] / 255.0 * (rfc3548chars.length - 1))];
 }
 return secret;
},
```

**3. Algorithm:**

It worked on my side for some time sending it like you did *&algorithm=SHA-1* . Then somehow it wont and I had to send it like *&algorithm=SHA1*. But anyway SHA-1/SHA1 is the default algorithm the Google Authenticator uses so I don't send it anyhow anymore.

I now generate Google Authenticator readable otpauth's like this one:

```
otpauth://totp/test?secret=QePxfLm3PViiJvE2HCRNIsGxmdOJD5KP&issuer=Test&digits=6&period=30
```

I commented my suggestions to your example:

```
otpauth://totp/TEST:asfadsf?secret=CBPhavYImNauHrVP9KuoR5eE2fO-b_7s&issuer=TEST&algorithm=SHA-1&digits=6&period=30
               \__________/        \______________________________/             \_____________/
                    |                               |                                   +----------> 3.)
                    |                               +----------------------------------------------> 2.)
                    +------------------------------------------------------------------------------> 1.)
```

Comment: wow what an answer, number 2 is exactly what i needed. If im using your secret generate function it is working.My function generated a string with 0,1,8 and 9 in it, so it was not base32 (RFC 3548/4648). thx and nice work